# Comparison of one Columns with every other columns in data frame entry wise for data quality

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame which is mix of numerical and categorical variables       ( Total 200 columns). I need to generate rules based on this data frame ( in short data quality without any labels in the data). Example: If column A is populated then column B should also be populated most of the times can be Rule 1.

So, to start with I thought to capture index of columns where value is not null in a list. And then do set operation to find overlap between two columns.
Please let me know if my approach is correct. Or is there any other better approach.

So, I started writing the code for it and I am getting all zeros in the matrix. Here is the code for it:

````
matrix={}
dat = np.zeros((len(columns),len(columns)))
for col in (columns):
    matrix[col]=data[data[col].notnull()].index.tolist()
    #print(matrix)


matrix2=pd.DataFrame(matrix.items())
matrix2 = pd.DataFrame(matrix2).reset_index()
matrix2.columns = ['index','variable', 'value']
matrix2=matrix2[["variable","value"]]


values1=list(matrix2["value"])

for i in range(len(columns)):
    for j in range(len(columns)):
        seta=set(values1[i])
        setb=set(values1[j])
        overlap= seta & setb

        result = (len(overlap) / 1000000) * 100
    dat[i,j]=result
print(dat)  


I am getting all zeros in the matrix.```

Values1 contains index position of row where value is not null.

    Values1
     []
     [1,2,3,4..10000]
       ..
       ..
     [1,....,900]
````

Comment: Could you give a reduced example of your matrix and show how you get the columns values?

Comment: Mentioned in the question above.

Comment: matrix is empty and columns is not defined, how is that an example

Comment: I am populating matrix with the values in the loop.